# Include additional data into iPhone backup files

Tags: iphone, backup, restore, migration

I have two iPhone backups available, one recent and one older.

Is it possible to inject/include/simply add content from my recent backup to the older one?

So that when the iPhone is restored from the older backup, the content from the recent one would be restored as well.

I have some apps installed that don't give me any option to export my content but I have to restore to the earlier backup missing the app or its content.

Comment: I wonder if you backed up via Time machine if you can handpick certain data to be restored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using various third party backup and restore software. I like iMazing and know there are a few others out there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can insert extra data into an existing backup.

Comment: Because there is nothing else here I will accept this answer. Maybe someone will come with some method sometime in the future (hope so :) ).